# Confused about filebeat AWS support

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, filebeat

We are deploying multi-region (and possibly multi-cloud in the future).
Our ElasticSearch endpoint must thus be public.

I know I can add an IP-based policy on the AWS Elastic Search to essentially whitelist all endpoints which should be allowed to write their logs to the AWS ES service.

Looking for a "saner" alternative, I came across:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-connect-beats-to-aws-elasticsearch-with-authentication/83465
and specially
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=294252

the latter specifically saying:

> Filebeat doesn't support IAM authentication so using it with this AWS
>   Elasticsearch service typically doesn't work.

However, I found this:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-module-aws.html#aws-credentials-options

which is the `filebeat` `aws` module, which seems to suggest that it actually may support it.

Couldn't find any official documentation nor blog which confirms that I could use `filebeat` on remote machines to send (authenticated? signed?) logs to a public AWS ElasticSearch endpoint, allowing me to keep the policy open without having to put a whitelist (or maybe I need both).

Comment: Those config settings you linked are for S3 input/output, not for ES input. AWS added support for cognito authentication to ES, so there are alternatives to IAM authentication now. fluentd and fluentbit can both handle ES IAM authentication on AWS and a lot more popular than filebeat/logstash these days.

Comment: Thank you. this is the info I needed.